# It is possible to monitor Apps usage on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process

It is possible in iOS to monitor Apps usage?. So, it is possible to answer the question: how much time I've spent on Facebook apps?

Comment: No, this would be a huge breach of privacy,

Comment: Its possible with your App with help of third party analytic tools such as Flurry.

Comment: I guess it would always be true if your monitoring apps says "too much"

Comment: I agree with GoodSp33d...